# How to remove a particular grid line corresponding to a custom xtick on a log scale axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to remove the vertical grid line corresponding to the custom xtick (displayed at x = 71 in the below picture). I could remove a horizontal grid line corresponding to the ytick 701 in the below picture by using a hack : since I have no minor tick on the y axis, I defined the custom ytick corresponding to the line that points toward the maximum and crosses the y axis as a minor tick, and then I disabled grid lines for minor ticks on the y axis. Unfortunately I cannot use the same hack on the x axis without disabling the grid lines of the minor ticks and that's something I'd like to avoid at all costs.

Below is a not so minimal albeit still WE.

There are many things I don't understand, the 2 majors are why does

```
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
```

not return the locs and labels that are plotted and why I don't get xticks labels displayed as 10^x where x = 0, 1, 2 and 3 but that's outside the scope of the original question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.grid(True)
import numpy as np

# Generate data
x_data = np.arange(1, 1000 , 10)
y_data = np.random.lognormal(1e-5, 3, len(x_data))
y_max = max(y_data) 

# plot
plt.xscale('log')
import math
ratio_log = math.log(x_data[np.argmax(y_data)]) / math.log(max(x_data)) # I need to do this in order to plot a horizontal red dashed line that points to the max and do not extend any further.
plt.axhline(y=y_max, xmin=0, xmax = ratio_log, color='r', linestyle='--')  # horizontal line pointing to the max y value. 
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([1, max(x_data)]) # Limits for the x axis.

# custom ticks and labels
# First yticks because I'm able to achieve what I seek
axes.set_yticks([int(y_max)], minor=True) # Sets the custom ytick as a minor one.
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
axes.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.0f"))          
axes.yaxis.grid(False, which='minor') # Removes minor yticks grid. Since I only have my custom yticks as a minor one, this will disable only the grid line corresponding to that ytick. That's a hack.         
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=y_max / 3.3) # this locator puts ticks at regular intervals. I ensure the y axis ticks look ok.
axes.yaxis.set_major_locator(loc)

# Now xticks. I'm having a lot of difficulty here, unable to remove the grid of a particular custom xticks.
locs, labels = plt.xticks() # Strangely, this doesn't return the locs and labels that are plotted. There are indeed 2 values that aren't displayed in the plot, here 1.00000000e-01 and 1.00000000e+04. I've got to remove them before I can append my custom loc and label.

# This means that if I do: plt.xticks(locs, labels) right here, it would enlarge both the lower and upper limits on the x axis... I fail to see how that's intuitive or useful at all. Might this be a bug?
locs = np.append(locs[1:-1], np.asarray(x_data[np.argmax(y_data)])) # One of the ugliest hack I have ever seen... to get correct ticks and labels.
labels = (str(int(loc)) for loc in locs) # Just visuals to get integers on the axis.
plt.xticks(locs, labels) # updates the xticks and labels.
plt.plot((x_data[np.argmax(y_data)], x_data[np.argmax(y_data)]), (0, y_max), 'r--') # vertical line that points to the max. Non OO way to do it, so a bad way.
plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.savefig('grid_prob.png')
plt.close()
```

Example picture below (the code outputs a different picture each time it is executed, but the problem appears in all pictures).

[image: Output file illustrating the problem I have.]

Comment: The problem may be a valid one, but i have problems understanding the issue. As i see it, you manually add the grid at position 71; then you ask how to remove it. Wouldn't it be easier not to show the grid at all and instead add a simple line where ever you need it?

Comment: I don't see where I add the grid at position 71 manually. I see that I enabled the grid with plt.grid(True) and that's all I've done related to the grid for the x axis. Of course I added xticks, but not a grid manually, unless I'm missing something. To answer your question, I don't know. However your comment helped me to solve the problem (although I've done it inefficiently). See the answer I posted. Also, if you have a more efficient way to achieve the same result, for instance without loading the grid with plt.grid(True) or maybe even by using .set_visible(), I'd be glad to accept your

Comment: answer. I also realize that I only added lines of code, making the code more complex, so I probably didn't solve the problem the exact way you mentioned. So feel free to go ahead and post your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Credit for the idea goes to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest to whom I am extremely grateful.

I removed the grid with

```
axes.xaxis.grid(False, which='both')
```

, then I added a grid correspond to each xtick except the custom one with the following loop:

```
for loc in locs[1:-1]:
    if loc != x_data[np.argmax(y_data)]:
        plt.axvline(x=loc, color = 'grey', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 0.4)
```

Insert this code just before the line

```
plt.xticks(locs, labels) # updates the xticks and labels.
```

Example of output picture below.
[image: no problem now.]