# Remove a grid line created from custom ticks in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In first place, sorry for my English, and in the second place, sorry for my code skills.

All I want is to remove a grid line that is created automatically from my custom xticks and yticks lists. I need to notify a point in the plot and I have spent over 2 hours reading all kind of solutions that exceeds my knowledge by far. No solution I found yet.

[![The plot][1]][1]

All I did is create custom ticks for Y and X axis:

```
ticks_x=[0.2,Vc,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2]
ticks_y=[-50,0,Pc,50,100,150,200]
xticks(ticks_x)
yticks(ticks_y)
grid(lw=0.2,color="k")
```

Could someone help me, please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess, you should remove 'Vc' and 'PC' from ticks_x and ticks_y respectively.

Comment: Looks like a possible solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988872/how-to-remove-a-particular-grid-line-corresponding-to-a-custom-xtick-on-a-log-sc)

Comment: @sehigle the thing is that I need to show the value of that point, this is why I have to add them to custom ticks

Comment: @G.Anderson I've read all that post, that solution works only in that case, not in mine, or at least I have no idea how to try it on my code.

Comment: Could you give a minimal code example?

Comment: Thanks @G.Anderson, I found the solution there. This was the third time I came to that link and finally I was able to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The key was to read slowly and try to do the same method in my code as it is shown here:

[How to remove a particular grid line corresponding to a custom xtick on a log scale axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988872/how-to-remove-a-particular-grid-line-corresponding-to-a-custom-xtick-on-a-log-sc)

I managed to solve it by making a custom grid this way:

```
ticks_x=[0.2,Vc,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2]
ticks_y=[-50,0,Pc,50,100,150,200]
xticks(ticks_x)
yticks(ticks_y)

for x1 in ticks_x:
    if x1!= Vc:
        axvline(x=x1, color = 'k', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 0.2)

for y1 in ticks_y:
    if y1!= Pc:
        axhline(y=y1, color = 'k', linestyle = '-', linewidth = 0.2)
```

[image: Solved]

Comment: the actual solution that you put in the question should better be here. Can you please move it?

Comment: Done! No images here because I need at least 10 reputation, but it is still in the question!

Comment: Thanks mate! I didn't realize they make stuff so hard for noobies. I guess it's to protect against spam or something. Anyways, I removed the answer from the question and moved the figure down here. That's how it should be.